# What is a Symbol (as in "Symbol Calculus")?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, definition, vector-bundles, pseudo-differential-operators

I have been reading through several papers on Deformation Quantization and the terms "symbol" and "symbol calculus" keep cropping up. I am somewhat well acquainted with most of the basic notions in differential geometry, but I have yet to run into this in any textbook and I'm having a hard time finding a definition for this.

Here's an excerpt of the paper *"On representations of star product algebras over cotangent spaces on Hermitian line bundles"* by Bordemann et al. where the term is used:

> ... Under an *operator representation* we understand a $\mathbb{C}$-linear assignment of a pseudo-differential operator $\mathrm{Op}_{\hbar}(a)$ on $\Gamma^\infty(L)$ [smooth sections of a Hermitian line bundle $L$ over $Q$] for every $\hbar\in \mathbb{R}^+$ ... and every symbol $a\in S^\infty(Q)\subset C^\infty(T^*Q)$...

I understand that $S^\infty(Q)$ is the set of smooth symbols on $Q$, which somehow is a subset of smooth functions on $T^*Q$, but I am still somewhat confused. What is a "symbol"?

Comment: I suggest looking up expositions of pseudodifferential operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$. After you get the idea there, you can look up references on pseudodifferential operators on manifolds.